# Fixed repeated values in sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql select statement which returns the records as follows.

```
Months | Output 
-------+-------
Jan'13 |   10  
feb'13 |   12   
Mar'13 |   14   
Apr'13 |   15   
May'13 |   11  
Jun'13 |   14
```

Now i want the output of the query as follows.

```
Months | Output Quarter   
-------+---------------
Jan'13 |   10 1  
feb'13 |   12 1  
Mar'13 |   14 1  
Apr'13 |   15 2  
May'13 |   11 2 
Jun'13 |   14 2
```

For every three records of the output I need a repeating value like above.

Comment: What's datatype of `months` column?

Comment: its is of Varchar type @Uriil

Comment: And expected quarter for Jan'14, will be 1, correct?

Comment: nope.. It will be 5 for Jan'14 and 6 for Apr'14.. It goes on until the records returned by my query exists @Uriil

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
       ('Jan''13', 10),
       ('feb''13', 12),
       ('Jun''13', 14),
       ('Mar''13', 14),
       ('Apr''13', 15),
       ('May''13', 11)

SELECT      months, [output], 
            DATEPART(QUARTER,REPLACE('1 ' + months,'''',' ')) AS Quarter
FROM        @TestTable
ORDER BY    3 -- Quarter
```

Month format "mmm'yy" is converted into "1 mmm yy" format. Eg: `Jan'13 => 1 Jan 13`
Then get the Quarter using DATEPART.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.months, t.output,
       ((row_number() over (order by months) + 2) / 3) as quarter
from (your query here) t
```

Alternatively, you might want the `quarter` option to `datepart()`, but you don't have enough information in the question to explain how to do this.

Comment: I just need a way to group the months as quarters in order to be used in SSRS report. so i thought by repeating a single value for every three records I can have a column that can be used to group the records as quarter.

Comment: If you want to get quarter in SSRS, just use DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter, <DATETIME>) function. Of course, you need to convert month string to DateTime type first.

Comment: When I use the above code the records get grouped by months. and the output is like 1 for apr13,apr14 and apr15 and 2 for aug13,aug14,aug15...

Comment: You should use an actual date value whose ordering is the same as the monthsç

Answer (score 0):

Complement the previous answer (Gordon Linoff)

```
declare @TestTable table (months varchar(20), [output] int)

insert into @TestTable
values
('Jan''13',     10),
('feb''13',     12),
('Mar''13',     14),
('Apr''13',     15),
('May''13',     11),
('Jun''13',     14)

SELECT 
  (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by ([output])) + 2) / 3 AS 'quarter', 
    months, [output]
FROM @TestTable
```

You have to set right ORDER BY for your data.

Comment: As I said, you have to set right ORDER BY. I don't know what table schema you have. If there is some datetime field then order by it. I months is datetime (but other format) convert it and then sort by months. Other case - make somthing that order by will be correct. You can even make some sub-query for it (as Gordon LInoff show)

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL should work:

```
select Months, Output, DATEPART(Q, '1/' + SUBSTRING(Months, 1, 3) + '/' + SUBSTRING(Months, 5, 2)) as Quarter
```

This is creating a date of the format '1/' + monthname + '/' + year and getting the quarter the field belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

May be this would be helpful:

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET( LOWER( SUBSTRING( DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y\'%b') , 4, 3) ) ,'jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec') DIV 4 + 1 AS Quarter;

+---------+
| Quarter |
+---------+
|       2 |
+---------+
```

( I used `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y\'%b')` instead of your `Months` value here )

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TestTable table (months VARCHAR(10),output INT)
INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
       ('Jan''13', 10),
       ('feb''13', 12),
       ('Jun''13', 14),
       ('Mar''13', 14),
       ('Apr''13', 15),
       ('May''13', 11)

SELECT months, [output], CASE LEFT(REPLACE(months,'''',''),3) WHEN   'Jan' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'feb' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Mar' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Apr' THEN 2
            WHEN 'May' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Jun' THEN 2
          END As Monthss
FROM @TestTable
ORDER BY DATEPART(QUARTER,REPLACE('1 ' + months,'''',' ')) ,3
```